# Como alterar ordem dos parâmetros no Oracle SQL Developer

Tags: sql, oracle, sqldeveloper

Estou com uma dúvida referente a ordem dos parâmetros dentro do SQL `developer`.
`Query` de exemplo:

```
select *      
from conta_paciente  
where cd_convenio = :cd_conv   
and dt_conta between :dti and :dt
```

Nas versões antigas os parâmetros ficavam na ordem que eu coloquei no select conforme exemplo abaixo:
[image: versão antiga]

Já na versão mais recente, os parâmetros estão ficando em ordem alfabética, conforme exemplo abaixo:
[image: Versão Nova]

Pode-se parecer algo bobo mas durante a realização da query facilita quando a ordem fica exatamente a mesma do script.

Answer (score -1):

Olá, Gabriel.

Você pode usar "Colunas Invisíveis e Ordenação de Colunas" para resolver o seu caso.

Na versão do Oracle 12c, para reorganizar as colunas logicamente, você pode usar o "VISIBLE".

**Exemplo:**

Criar a tabela

```
CREATE TABLE t (
    a INT,
    b INT,
    d INT,
    e INT
);
```

Adicionar uma coluna:

```
ALTER TABLE t ADD (c INT);
```

Mover a coluna para o meio:

```
ALTER TABLE t MODIFY (d INVISIBLE, e INVISIBLE);
ALTER TABLE t MODIFY (d VISIBLE, e VISIBLE);
```

DESCRIBE t;

```
Name
----
A
B
C
D
E
```

> Quando você torna visível uma coluna invisível, a coluna
>   é incluída na ordem das colunas da tabela como a última coluna.

[Link da documentação](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ADMIN/tables.htm#ADMIN-GUID-38DBFC2E-FC6C-46E2-A7A1-6FA703F9DC01)

Comment: Cara, isso não tem nada a ver com o que ele perguntou